Откуда пошло слово ЕБ@ЛО для лица
Хлебало - лицо понятно откуда пошло. Производитель действия "хлебать" расположен на лице.
Табло - лицо понятно откуда пошло. Результат на табле/лице написан.
Еб@ло - как тут связан производитель действия с лицом ???

Знатоки обсценной лексики!
Предлагаю вам две статьи для вашего образования.

Когда и почему появилось слово еб++ло для обозначения лица.

Что означает выражение еб++ло на ноль.


Цитировать не буду, сами прочитаете. Надеюсь, что вам будет полезен этот материал.

По приведенным Вами ссылкам полностью повторяется один из вариантов, который изложен в моем ответе. Вы именно поэтому не стали цитировать, а просто дали ссылку? Ладно, я процитирую за Вас: Здесь смысл в том, что ртом можно не только принимать пищу, в него можно еб@ть. Со временем, "еблом" стали называть не только рот, но и всё лицо, что заметно упростило процесс общения.

Впрочем, я рад, что приведенными ссылками Вы подтверждаете правильность моего ответа, данного задолго до Вашего. Жаль только, что тот ресурс, на который Вы ссылаетесь, сложно отнести к сколь бы то ни было серьезным лингвистическим источникам, за ссылки на которые Вы так радели в комментарии к моему ответу.

Мне совершенно без разницы, кто и что разделяет, не моя тема. Я всего лишь хотела сказать, что ваша лингвистическая проблема не так сложна. Вы могли бы сами все это найти в Сети, а может и еще какие "откровения", для вас интересные. И хотя бы вид метафорического переноса обозначили, чтобы на лингвистику было похоже.

Я не смог найти в сети авторитетный лингвистический источник, который бы описывал этимологию этого слова. Судя по тому, какие ссылки Вы привели вместо ссылок на такой источник, Вам тоже не удалось этого сделать.

Ivan Olshansky, предлагаю вам обсудить какую-нибудь другую тему, неужели нам с вами поговорить больше не о чем))  Вот интересный вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/482209/Грамотно-ли-будет-написать-Он-был-построен-годом-то-бишь-использовать  Думаю, как на него ответить)  У вас есть варианты?

Обычно слово "еб@ло" в качестве определения лица подразумевает пренебрежительный оттенок. Используя это слово, говорящий подразумевает, что это лицо можно "выеб@ть" (совершить с этим лицом оральный половой акт) или можно по нему "въеб@ть"/"уеб@ть" (ударить это лицо), и что ни для чего большего это лицо не подходит.
Собственно это и определяет этимологию слова "еб@ло".
"Еб@ло" - это нечто, что можно "выеб@ть", или по чему можно "въеб@ть".

Звучит складно. Но как-то у меня интуитивно не вяжется одно с другим.

@user190920, В обсценной лексике вообще часто ключевое значение имеет не логика, а эмоциональный окрас.

Это мнение, а не ответ.  Приводите ссылки на лингвистические источники. С такими ответами вопрос можно закрыть, а иначе весь Интернет здесь соберется.

@Sharon, я не встречал слова "еб@ло" в словарях, которые можно было бы назвать авторитетными источниками. Но если Вы зададите вопрос об этимологии этого слова кому-либо, кто использует его в повседневной жизни, то вряд ли услышите от этого человека какие-либо версии, отличные от двух, приведенных выше. Более того, скорее всего Вам дополнительно объяснят, что данное происхождение настолько очевидно, что они удивлены тем, что у Вас возник этот вопрос. Возможно, они Вам это скажут чуть-чуть другими словами, но суть будет приблизительно такая.

Тогда такие вопросы нужно не с лингвистами обсуждать, а где-нибудь в соответствующих чатах) Если нет источников, то расскажите о грамматике суффиксов, о переносных (метафорических) значениях. Хотя о чем-то расскажите. Автора вопроса ваш ответ тоже не очень устроил - не вяжется у него одно с другим.  И  "ваш эмоциональный окрас" тоже ни о чем не говорит, если вы не раскрываете отнесенность одного  предмета к другому.  Одни общие слова без понятного смысла.

Кстати, я обратила внимание на то, что люди спрашивают: у вас можно обсуждать такие темы, прежде чем задавать такие вопросы.? И мы вроде бы считаем, что можно, так как это лингвистическая тема.

Предложу свою версию, которая мне кажется наиболее правдоподобной, но в правильности тоже не уверен.
ЕБ@ЛО/3БЛО/3БАЛЬНИК , на мой взгляд, активный производитель действия. Тут для большей обоснованности надо провести анализ использования этих суффиксов для активных и пассивных производителей действия в РЯ, но мне что-то лень.
Так вот, сабж, активно используется в процессе целования-любования. То есть 3БЛЯ тут в широком смысле подразумевается.
