Грамотно ли будет написать: "Он был построен **** годом"?, то бишь использовать и числительное, и существительное в творительном падеже?
Сразу будет адекватно подумать, что правильный вариант с родительным падежом - "построен в **** году", и так оно и будет. Однако хотелось бы знать, может ли использоваться вариант с творительным падежом, и если нет, то почему?


Творительный падеж (Т. п.) обозначает орудийную семантику, то есть в обобщенном смысле способствует совершению действия,  а также  придает ему определенный вид, образ.

В частности Т.п. используется для обозначения времени и пространства, когда и где совершается действие: идти лесом, полем, вернуться вечером, отдыхать летом. Также с предлогами: отдохнуть перед учебой, рассказать за ужином.

Но вот сказать "Храм был построен годом..." нельзя. В современном языке используется предложный падеж: Храм был построен в 1380 году (П. п.). В летописях использовался В.п. Так,  о строительстве в Новгороде Софийского собора в летописях сообщается лаконично: «В лето/в год 6553.


Винительный падеж указывает точную дату (в этот год), а предложный — на период (в этом году).

Еще интересный вариант: Удивительны и сроки строительства храма. Обычно церковь строили за 3-4 сезона, но «оную церковь единым летом соверши...», т. е храм был возведен за один год. Но здесь оценочное значение: одним годом —  за один год.

ВЫВОД. Если нужен стилизованный вариант, то надо написать: Он был построен в лето/в год..."

"Он ушел прошлым годом" - абсолютно нормальная фраза с творительным времени...

Лексически не правильно. Есть контексты, когда творительный падеж употребляется для обозначения времени постройки:
Он был построен третьим темпом

Но уже если мы заменим "темп" на "очередь", то лексическая сочетаемость начинает быть под вопросом:
Он был построен третьей очередью\второй пятилеткой

